# Force uninstall an app?

Tags: 8.1, apps, store, foursquare

**Is there any way to force an app on the SD card to be uninstalled?**

I cannot open one of the apps on my phone (Swarm).

- When I hold on to it and select Uninstall, nothing happens.
- It no longer shows up in Storage Sense, under applications in phone memory or SD card.
- When I look for this app in the Store, it gives the option to install. However, when I select Install, it stays in the Downloads section of the store and says Pending. Tried with WiFi and cellular data. When I click on it on the Downloads section, it says:

`Just a little longer and Swarm will be installed`

However, nothing happens even after hours of waiting.

**Here are the details:**

```
Phone: Lumia 521
OS: WP 8.1
```

**Additional Notes:**

At first, I had all apps installed on the phone memory.

When I got a SD card, I moved all apps that were allowed to be moved to the SD Card.

Afterwards all apps worked well.

There were several instances when the phone was not responding at all. And I had to remove the battery and put it back in to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the memory card and view the contents on a PC with 'show hidden files' ON.
Delete the app if you see it there.
Before you replace the card, try an uninstall first. If that doesn't work, do a phone RESET. Make sure that all data you want kept is uploaded to One Drive of backed up locally.